# Bound in the Hille-Yosida Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, unbounded-operators

I saw the following version of the Hille-Yosida theorem in a book:

[image]

However, from the proof that I have seen, they only proof the bound

$$\left|\left|\frac{\partial Y}{\partial s}(s)\right|\right|=\left|\left|AY(s)\right|\right| \le \left|\left|AY_0\right|\right|$$

I know that the proof of the theorem follows from studying the Yosida approximations, but I am unable to prove $\left|\left|AY(s)\right|\right| \le \frac 1s\left|\left|Y_0\right|\right|$ from that.

Comment: This theorem is proved in Brezis "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations", Theorem 7.7. The proof is a bit lengthy, and I am a bit too lazy to copy it here as an answer, but as far as I can tell, it is detailed and well-written (and *does* prove what you want). By the way, note that the bound $\|AY(s)\| \leq \|AY_0\|$ only makes sense if $Y_0 \in D(A)$ (or you might say that $\|AY_0\|=\infty$ if $Y_0 \notin D(A)$ I guess...).

Comment: I'm also studying this theorem. Could you share the book containing the version in your question?

Comment: @Akira The book is "Morse theory and Floer homology" by Audin and Damien. It does not contain a proof.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaboration!